# Scale an area lamp that seems to be locked

Tags: scale

the area lamp seems to be locked and cannot be scaled.
how to unlock it to be able to scale it?
edit:
it seems my camera's limit (focus) also locked. the distance cannot be adjusted.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check if the Scale properties of the area light aren't locked:

[image]

About the camera, you could check these properties:

[image]

Comment: i've checked those earlier. just found out it's correcter after fiddling around. though it's fixed for now, i am not sure which part that i did fixed the issues. whether "manipulate centre point", "pivot centres" or anything else.

Comment: Oh, okay! Sometimes these weird things happen, if you discover what you did you can post here so that other people that have the same problem can see what's wrong!